# RGB Value for UITableViewCell SelectionStyle Blue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, selection, rgb, uicolor

I am doing some work with a custom UITableViewCell,and I am trying to find out the RGB value of the UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue. For long detailed reasons, I will not be using the delivered selection style. Is the blue selection style color solid (it looks to be so) or a gradient? Any help or a point in the right direction to replicate this color/style would be appreciated.

Comment: Download http://iconfactory.com/software/xscope for a trial and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an image editing program such as Graphic Converter.  With most of these when one entered color selection mode there is usually a pointer that can be hovered over the screen and it will display the color values.  I also will take a screenshot, open it in GC and display it at 200% or 400% to get accurate colors and sizes.

Comment: This functionality is build into XCode also. Open up a XIB, open the attribute editor and click on some object with a color. In the Attribute editor click on the area to set the color to make the color wheel window come up. 
Above the color wheel you can see a large colored block with a magnifying glass. Click on the magnifying glass and use it to pick any color anywhere on your monitor.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help everyone. I got Digital Color Meter and I'm pretty sure the gradient is:
R .02  G .549, B .961, A 1
R .004 G .365  B .902  A 1
Let me know if you find it's something else!